# Weird compilation issue- no compiler errors for unrecognised class

Tags: c++, debugging, header, compilation, compiler-errors

I have too much code to post, but I keep getting a repeated compile error that class `Orderbk` is not recognised throughout my project.

The weirdest thing is that there are no actual compile errors within `Orderbk` (which would understandably cause all other classes to not recognize it).

Could someone please give me clues what could possibly be wrong from the fact my compiler doesn't see a problem inside `Orderbk`, but every class referencing `Orderbk` reports it undefined?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FXDcr (Intel C++ 13.0), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Derivative.cpp
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(29): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk getOrderbk();
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(33): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk orderbk;
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Stk.h(35): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>          Orderbk orderbk;
1>          ^
1>  
1>  FXDcr.cpp
1>  FXMsg.cpp
1>  Fut.cpp
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(29): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk getOrderbk();
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(33): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk orderbk;
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Stk.h(35): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>          Orderbk orderbk;
1>          ^
1>  
1>  Index.cpp
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(29): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk getOrderbk();
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(33): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk orderbk;
1>      ^
1>  
1>  Instr.cpp
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Stk.h(13): error : not a class or struct name
1>    class Stock : public Instr {
1>                         ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Stk.h(35): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>          Orderbk orderbk;
1>          ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Mappings.h(31): error : identifier "Instr" is undefined
1>      static unordered_map<string, boost::shared_ptr<Instr> > GetDictOfAllInstrs();
1>                                                     ^
1>  
1>  Main.cpp
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(29): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk getOrderbk();
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(33): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk orderbk;
1>      ^
1>  
1>  Mappings.cpp
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(29): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk getOrderbk();
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(33): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk orderbk;
1>      ^
1>  
1>  Order.cpp
1>  Stock.cpp
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(29): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk getOrderbk();
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(33): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk orderbk;
1>      ^
1>  
1>  SIA.cpp
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(29): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk getOrderbk();
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Instr.h(33): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>      Orderbk orderbk;
1>      ^
1>  
1>C:\DXDcr\FXDcr\Stk.h(35): error : identifier "Orderbk" is undefined
1>          Orderbk orderbk;
1>          ^
1>  
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

EDIT all my header files are of the format:

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H
class CLASS{

};
#endif
```

Comment: Did you include the header of `Orderbk`?

Comment: @xorguy I didn't forget it from every single other .cpp file. It has to be something wrong with Orderbk.

Comment: it could be that your includes introduce circular dependencies. Use forward class declarations to break those.

Comment: @PavelBeliy see my edit at bottom of question- those #ifndef should eliminate circular references?

Comment: Maybe you need to link to a library? Do you have a makefile?

Comment: no they dont. these include guards are for completely different thing, to guard against double declarations.

Comment: @FlorinPetriuc the only library I am using is boost::shared_ptr and that is being recognized by the compiler.

Comment: i meant double definitions ofc.

Comment: @PavelBeliy whats the easiest way for me to check?

Comment: Did you include all the CPP files in your makefile? How are you compiling?

Comment: i can't think of any other possible cause of these errors(assuming you didn't make completely stupid mistakes and forgot to include your files before using them), so i would just write forward declarations everywhere, they don't hurt

Comment: @FlorinPetriuc these are compile-time errors, not link-time

Comment: @FlorinPetriuc I am using Visual Studio, so I am just building the project via the GUI.

Comment: For each include file, make a list of all include files it recursively uses. If it ever recursively includes itself, you have a problem. Use /showIncludes option for the MS compiler (don't know about the Intel one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A header file can only be included only once in every compilation unit to avoid duplicate definitions. This is done with `#ifdef`s or other solutions.

If you have headers which depend on each other, you will get a header file loop which results in the kind of errors you refer to in your question.

Here is an example (I just use `#pragma once` to show that the file is only included once, might not work everywhere):

Header file `a.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "b.h"
class A {
    B b_instance;
};
```

Header file `b.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "a.h"
class B {
    A a_instance;
};
```

Code file `program.cpp`

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

When you compile `program.cpp`, `a.h` is included first. The first thing `a.h` does is to include `b.h`. `b.h` then tries to include `a.h`, but it will be ignore because it's already included. When class B is then parsed, it can't find `A` because we haven't gotten that far in `a.h` yet.

One solution to this is to use pointers in the heeader file (if possible).

Header file `b.h`

```
#pragma once
class A;
class B {
    A *a_instance;
    public:
    int do_stuff();
};
```

Whit this forward-definition of `class A`, I can use pointers to it since the compilers always knows the size of them. I cannot, however, do `a_instance = new A();` or use members of `A`, this has to go in `b.cpp`!

Code file `b.cpp`

```
#include "a.h"
int B::do_stuff() {
        a_instance = new A();
        // Or this
        A my_instance;
}
```

Comment: Just put "#pragma once" at the top of each of my header files and I still get the same problem?

Comment: The `#pragma once` is not my solution, it just shows that headers are only included once. I think you have code in your header files which depend on eachoter, like in my example where both `a.h` and `b.h` depend on eachother, making the compilation fail.

Comment: Ok I have found the cyclic reference :) Will try to re-write it and let you know if it works!

Comment: I had two! All sorted now :)